# Calling JS function on Kendo Grid doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid with some statistic columns to my items (count, average, percents, etc.). When I try to call a JS function to show maximum of 2 decimal places and trim trailing zeroes, the function doesn't work.

However, on browser console it works, so when I added a Timeout function to my JS, it works. But for several reasons, this is not the solution I want

The Kendo Grid for illustration:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<StatisticsItemsModel>()
    .Name("grid-list")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(t => t.Description).Title("Description").Width(50)
            .ClientTemplate("#if (Description!= null) { if (IsNew == true) { #" + "<div style='text-align:right'>#: Description#</div>" + "# } else { #" + "<div style='text-align:right'><strong>#: Description#</strong></div>" + "# }} #");
        columns.Bound(t => t.Count).Width(100).Title("Count").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right" });
        columns.Bound(t => t.Percent).Width(100).Title("Percent").Format("{0:##.## %}").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right" });
        columns.Bound(t => t.Average).Width(100).Title("Average").Format("{0:n2}").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right", @class = "StatisticAverage" });
    })
    .DataSource(dataBinding => dataBinding
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .Read(read => read.Action("DataGridStatistics", "Filter", new { id = Model.Id })
    )
    )
)
```

Currently working JS Function with Timeout:

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $(".StatisticAverage").each(function (i, obj) {
                if ($(this).text() != "") {
                    var textVal = $(this).text().replace(",", ".");
                    var numberVal = parseFloat(textVal);
                    r = (+numberVal).toFixed(2).replace(/([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+[1-9])?)(\.?0+$)/, '$1');
                    $(this).text(r);
                }
            })
        }, 2000)
    });
```

Any ideas how to make this work properly without the Timeout function? How to make sure, the JS function executes only when the Kendo Grid is fully loaded?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `dataBound` event instead of the timeout. This will be triggered after data from the `dataSource` is bound to the grid.

[dataBound](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridEventBuilder#databoundsystemstring)

Code sample:

```
Html.Kendo().Grid<StatisticsItemsModel>()
  .Name("grid-list")
  .Events(e => e.DataBound("onDataBound"))
  .Columns....


function onDataBound() {
        // handle the data change event here...
    }
```

Comment: That might work, but unfortunately I have no idea how to make it work

Comment: Updated the answer with sample and doc.